# Semantic UI React Popup className is not added to parent element

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm using `<Popup />` from SUI-R and encountered this visual bug. Below is the picture of the visual bug:

[image]

So, the popup is under the content. What I expect it to show is like this:

[image]

Below is a code snippet from my project.

[image: sample snippet]

But it only shows when I add `z-index` on the parent element of the popup. So I used `className` props from the SUI-R docs, but it doesn't add to the parent element, but instead, it adds to its direct child.

[image]

The red marker is the parent while the green one is its child.

I'm using the latest version of SUI-R:

```
"semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
"semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.0",
```

How do I add a class in its parent element instead of its child? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
They made some changes in Popup that cause breaking changes. For more information, go to these links below:

GITHUB: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/pull/3947

SUI-R Docs: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/popup/#usage-popper

Comment: This behavior is normal in sematic ui sometimes. That is because of the HOCs they are using. Even if you try to add a class to the `Popup`, content is defined in a different element. What you have to do is write down a simple CSS query selector like this `.popup > .content`.

Comment: Hey @DushanRandika. Thanks for the reply! I see, but this is working on my previous projects. It adds to the parent element itself. They might've updated the codes in newer versions.

Comment: Yeah. Looks like they have rearranged some components  with HOC pattern.